# Can cookies be forced on a local site?

Tags: javascript

I have a little javascript application that I've written myself that helps with turning rasterized psds of websites into html + css.

It does stuff like create an image overlay, and then has sliders to edit the opacity, scale, z-index of the image, stuff like that.

I'd like the application to remember the slider settings in-between refreshes, though. Cookies can be used to store this information, but not when a site is local.

Can I force cookies for Chrome when the site is local?

Comment: What do you mean "site is local"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage or http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/

Comment: @JaredFarrish Hey jarred, using the localStorage function is working really well (providing I don't have a stroke and start using IE6 to develop). Do you want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In chrome cookies are either enabled from third party or disabled.
So you just set normal cookies and if they are not allowed then the functionality will not work

Answer (score 1):

Cookies should work fine on localhost, but they won't work if you're using file:// protocol. Cookies are handled by your web server and browser, I don't think it's possible for cookies to just work using the browser.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`.

See:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage
- http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Example:

- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/

Note that there are also (some legitimate) [complaints](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/there-is-no-simple-solution-for-local-storage/) about the state of storage technology like `localStorage`. For purposes of saving state (`sessionStorage` is also out there) or settings, probably not a big deal (complaints are mainly performance-related). Be careful treating it as a full-fledged DB alternative without learning more about the issues surrounding it's use.